# PHP session not working properly on server

Tags: php, apache

This is a weird problem and I really don't know how to explain it so please bear with me. The thing is I have a php project which has been coded from scratch(no template engine or frameworks), and it works fine on localhost, but as soon as I upload it on server, for some odd reason, the pages and session data seem to arrive from a cache. For example if I try to delete a value(by submitting a form), the page loads and still shows the value, if I then hit Ctrl+F5(force reload on FF), it loads correctly showing( or rather not showing) the deleted record.

Can this happen due to any server-side settings?

Comment: Use `error_reporting(1)` for first line of code and check errors.

Comment: and also use `ini_set('display_errors', true);` if needed

Comment: Error reporting is already on, plus I also checked the server's error logs...nothing so far

Comment: It absolutely can. Your web host might have transparent caching set up for instance. It's not clear if this is what's happening or not: if you can provide a more concrete example, it may clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

Try and clear all sessions from your browser. I have experienced something similar, it could be sessions set by your local host on the browser that is conflicting with it.

Try and set cache for php files to 0 using htaccess.